# Does the key of a React element need to be on a direct child?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say that in my render function I have an iteration like this:

```
{list.map((item) => (
  <Element key={item.key} item={item} />
)}
```

I assume that, to simplify, it's OK to make the "Element" component itself render the `key` in its render function (in the root element) so I can rewrite the iteration like this:

```
{list.map((item) => (
  <Element item={item} />
)}
```

But then let's say that in some specific case I need to wrap the Element in a div like this:

```
{list.map((item) => (
  <div>
    <Element item={item} />
  </div>
)}
```

Now the **direct child** of the "node array" is **not** carrying a `key` prop anymore!

However, this doesn't generate a warning in the console anymore.

So my question is: am I doing something that is not allowed / undefined behavior? Should I move the `key` from the "Element" component to the outer div? Or it doesn’t matter?

Comment: I'm skeptical of this not throwing a missing key warning. What version of react are you using?

Comment: *"I assume that, to simplify..."* - no, that's not OK. Look at https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe for the link. Super useful! I think you can make it an answer.

Comment: @azium I'm using React 16.12

Answer (score 0):

it's weird that you don't get missing key warning even thought it's not how you need to do it.
As @jonrsharpe send React tell you to put a key like your first code you don't need to do it inside the element this is not a good behavior.